# zip - difference between "." and "* .[^.]*" patterns when using -r flag

Tags: bash, terminal, zip

While recursively zipping a directory contents (including hidden files and directories) using `zip` command with `-r` flag, is there any difference between:

```
zip ../foo.zip -r .
```

and:

```
zip ../foo.zip -r * .[^.]*
```

or are they exactly the same?

First command should take current directory (`.`) as target and `-r` parameter should include by itself all hidden files and directories.

Second command, if i'm not wrong, matches all non-dot-files (first `*`) in current directory and then all files starting with `.` char, followed by any char but dot (`[^.]`) - so this excludes `..` going to parent directory.

I found second command in an example online, but i dont get the point of using it in place of the simpler first command, if it acts exactly the same way.

Also in POSIX shell script, ShellCheck complains about `* .[^.]*` notation which should be replaced with `./* .[!.]*`, and to me this is another good reason to not use it, if a simple `.` does the same job.

My guess is that in the example i found `zip ../foo.zip * .[^.]*` (without `-r` flag) command was taken and `-r` flag was simply added, without thinking that `-r` would have already taken care of including hidden files and directories if current path (`.`) was given as target in the place of `* .[^.]*`.

So my questions are: are those 2 commands equivalent when using the `-r` flag? Is my guess correct?

Comment: Are you asking about the shell globbing patterns, or are you asking about how `zip` interprets its arguments when running with the `-r` option?  These are two different questions.

Comment: @Kusalananda edited my question to be more clear